# integration test with testcontainer, both integrate mysql and rabbitMQ containers

Tags: mysql, rabbitmq, testcontainers, junit-jupiter

As we known, it's very easy to write down only rabbitMQ integration test with testcontainer.
But when I also introduce mysql integration test with testcontainer.

I found they have some conflict. When I only run IT of rabbitMQ, error occurrs for no DB to Mysql. and I need to add @Container for mysql, or else mysql can not find a container to access.

Currently I think of two solution:

1. exclude the database connection or something like JPA test ?
2. move mysql IT and MQ IT together to one class, so that will create the two containers

For 1. I don't know how to use the @annotation
For 2. I think it's not elegant

1. rabbitMQ Integration Test:

```kotlin
package com.example.myapp

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.util.TestPropertyValues
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status
import org.testcontainers.containers.RabbitMQContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@ContextConfiguration(initializers = [RabbitControllerTest.Initializer::class])
@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)
//class RabbitControllerTest : BaseIntegrationTest() {
//@DataJpaTest(
//    excludeAutoConfiguration =
//    [
//        DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class,
//        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration::class,
//        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration::class
//    ]
//)

//@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = [DemoApplication::class])
//        @WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class RabbitControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Autowired
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    companion object {
        @Container
        private val rabbitMQContainer = KRabbitMQContainer(image = "rabbitmq:3.7-management").withExposedPorts(5672)
//            .withExposedPorts(5673)
            .withVhost("/").withUser("admin", "admin").withPermission("/", "admin", ".*", ".*", ".*")
//            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))

//        @Container
//        private val mysqlContainer = KMySQLContainer(image = "mysql:8.0.22")
//            .withDatabaseName("myapp")

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun properties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
//            registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mysqlContainer::getJdbcUrl)
//            registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mysqlContainer::getPassword)
//            registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mysqlContainer::getUsername)
//            registry.add("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto") { "create-drop" }

//            rabbitMQ
            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.host") { rabbitMQContainer.host }
            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.port") { rabbitMQContainer.amqpPort }
//            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.port") { 5673 }
//            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.username", rabbitMQContainer::getAdminUsername)
//            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.password", rabbitMQContainer::getAdminPassword)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `should rabbitMQ send out message`() {
        val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(TodoRequest("Write a blog on Testcontainers"))
        this.mockMvc.perform(
            post("/set-foo").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json)
        ).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk)
    }
}

class KRabbitMQContainer(val image: String) : RabbitMQContainer(image)
```

2. controller using rabbitTemplate:

```kotlin
package com.example.myapp.rabbitmq

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class ExampleController {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var rabbitTemplate: RabbitTemplate

    @PostMapping("/set-foo")
    fun setFoo(@RequestBody value: String) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(MessagingConfig.FANOUT_EXCHANGE_NAME, "", value)
    }

}
```

3. application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}/myapp
```

4. build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.14.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["testcontainersVersion"] = "1.17.4"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
//  testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:mysql")

//    // testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.17.5")
    testImplementation("org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:rabbitmq:1.17.5")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.17.5")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    testImplementation("com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.14.2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test:2.4.3")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-junit:2.4.3")

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${property("testcontainersVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

plz notice that :

1. **   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") ** will automaticlly connect to database, if I comment out this, IT will not try to connect with database.
2. I have comment out the mysql container creation, if you revert back, the test will run successfully.

Thanks hope hear your precious voice

Comment: It's no clear for me what are you trying to achieve here. Can you expand more? What kind of tests want to write? integration tests? slice tests for repositories and rabbitmq clients? Take into account that using `@SpringBootTest` you will start the whole app context which will consider database and rabbitmq if those classes are present. If you want to write tests only for repositories then `@DataJpaTest` would be initializing only what you need. For rabbitmq, there is no such thing but you can use only the right configurations and your client.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez Hi Eddu, thanks for relpy first, and I think it's clear that I want to write **Ingtegration test with test containers** as the title description. And if you try the code, you will find @ SpringBootTest will autowire everyting, so if I only create a container with rabbitMQ but not provide mysql container, error occurs of datasource related

Comment: Running MySQL and RabbitMQ with Testcontainers will not conflict with each other in any way. It is unclear why you share code with so many commented-out lines, it makes it very hard to read and understand your goal.

I would suggest you share a reproducer repository on GitHub. The issue is about the Spring config here and not related to Testcontainers in any way. I also suggeest to use [Single Containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers), since you are struggeling with the implications of the test framework integration.

Comment: @KevinWittek thanks for your suggestion, it make sense. Comment out means plz ignore, just run the code is successful with only one testcontainer. will post more info, thanks for all of you